# Append to text file is not working correctly in a loop

Tags: c++

The following code is a function that is being called multiple times under runtime. The function contains a `for loop` where some text is written to a `stringstream` buffer. The problem is that only the data from the first (or last?) function call is inputed into the text file. I am having trouble to find a way to let the data append to the text file without anything being overwritten, just in a "one after another" manner.

```
void testItems(const TestObjectList* const testObject) {

      std::stringstream objectOutputBuffer;
      std::ofstream fileOutput("testlog.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);

      for (itr = testobjects.begin(); itr != testobjects.end(); itr++){

         objectOutputBuffer << some stuff getting written to the buffer in the loop << std::endl;

      }
      fileOutput << objectOutputBuffer.str() << "\n";
      //fileOutput.close();
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to provide enough code to actually run and reproduce the problem.

Comment: No need for more code :) Problem is in string stream but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Is it called in multiple threads?

Comment: @dvnguyen nope.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not with your `testobjects` list?  Are you certain there is more than one entry in it? I don't see a problem with your actual opening of `fileOutput` in append mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fileOutput.close()` is commented out, closing the file will probably fix.

Try to execute this:

```
int main() {
        std::ofstream f("f.txt");
        f << "this will be there\n";

        std::ofstream g("f.txt");
        g << "this will not\n";
}
```

The first string will be written to the file but not the second.

I suggest you to move the `std::ofstream fileOutput("testlog.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out)` outside the function and then pass `fileOutput` as parameter when you call it.

And when you are finished remember to close the file.

Comment: The stream's destructor should flush and close the stream just fine, unless there's a huge bug in OP's standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to specify the `std::ios::out` flag with a `std::ofstream` object since it already is set by default.  If you want to be able to append to the end of your file all you should really need to do is set the `std::ios::app` flag.

`std::ofstream fileOutput("testlog.txt", std::ios::app);`

Also while I don't think this is your problem, the newline character doesn't flush your stringstream buffer and force it to write to the file. I would recommend replacing your `"\n"` with `std::endl` which does flush the buffer just to be sure.

Comment: @GRC I just tested this again and you're right.  It works fine with just `std::ios::app` set.  I'll update my answer.